# Proofs about constructors matched with _

Tags: coq

Assume I have the following Set:

```
Inductive Many : Set := 
| aa: Many
| bb: Many
| cc: Many
(* | ... many more constructors *)
.
```

How can I proof in the `_` match, that `y<>aa`?

```
match x with
| aa     => true
| _ as y => (* how can i proof that y <> aa ? *)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it does not seem possible to get such a proof without some more work in pure Gallina. What you would like to write is:

```
  match x with
  | aa => true
  | y =>
    let yNOTaa : y <> aa := fun yaa =>
      eq_ind y (fun e => match e with aa => False | _ => True end) I aa yaa
    in false
  end
```

But that does not work quite well in Gallina, as it does not expand the wildcard into all possible cases, leaving `y` abstract in the `eq_ind` invocation. It does however work in tactic mode:

```
refine (
  match x with
  | aa => true
  | y =>
    let yNOTaa : y <> aa := fun yaa =>
      eq_ind y (fun e => match e with aa => False | _ => True end) I aa yaa
    in false
  end
).
```

But it actually builds the expanded term with all the branches.

---

I just found out that there is a way to have the Vernacular build the same term that the refine tactic would build. To do so, you have to force a return annotation mentioning the discriminee, like so:

```
Definition foo (x : many) : bool :=
  match x return (fun _ => bool) x with
  | aa => true
  | y =>
    let yNOTaa : y <> aa := fun yaa : y = aa =>
      @eq_ind many y (fun e => match e with aa => False | _ => True end) I aa yaa
    in false
  end
.
```

My guess is that the term elaboration differs whether the match is dependent or not...